# Arduino Uno to Particle Photon - Converting Code

Tags: c++, arduino

Please bear with me. I am an amateur programmer at Arduino, and have never used Particle photon before.

I used an Arduino Uno and wrote the attached code that detects heart beat and temperature using the Grove Ear clip heart beat sensor and the Grove Temperature sensor and then prints them in the console every 20 seconds. Previously, this code was written to show in an Grove OLED screen but later simplified it back to using it without the OLED screen.

I am now looking into using the same application and function using the same sensor on a Particle Photon (as it is smaller and has WiFi capability). I have never previously used this technology before but I saw online that it, more or less, uses the same code application. I have been through the sample codes for this online available on its website but I have no idea how to convert my code for the Arduino into code for the photon (Photon console compiles the code without any error but does not show any sensor data). Can someone either point me to the right direction/ appropriate online resources / help me change this code here to make it work on the Photon? (I just added the `Particle.publish()` wherever I was using Arduino's `Serial.println()` but it still doesn't print anything).

The result in the console shows:

```
Please be ready
This will now begin
```

then it prints number 1 to 20 every second followed by sensor readings.

Again sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your help.

I used direct codes from the documentation blog of the sensors (bottom of the page of the linked page):

[Grove heart bear sensor](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Ear-clip_Heart_Rate_Sensor/)
[Grove Temperature sensor](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Temperature_Sensor/)

```
#define LED 4//indicator, Grove - LED is connected with D4 of Arduino
boolean led_state = LOW;//state of LED, each time an external interrupt
                                //will change the state of LED
float tempa;
int tempPin = 0;
unsigned char counter;
unsigned long temp[21];
unsigned long sub;
bool data_effect=true;
unsigned int heart_rate;//the measurement result of heart rate

const int max_heartpluse_duty = 2000;//you can change it follow your system's request.
                        //2000 meams 2 seconds. System return error
                        //if the duty overtrip 2 second.
void setup()
{

    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
    Serial.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial){
  ;
  }
    Serial.println("Please be ready");
    delay(5000);
    arrayInit();
    Serial.println("This will now begin.");
    attachInterrupt(0, interrupt, RISING);//set interrupt 0,digital port 2
}
void loop()
{
    digitalWrite(LED, led_state);//Update the state of the indicator
}
/*Function: calculate the heart rate*/


void sum()
{
 if(data_effect)
    {
        heart_rate=1200000/(temp[20]-temp[0]);//60*20*1000/20_total_time
        Serial.print("Heart_rate_is:\t");
        Serial.println(heart_rate);
        tempa = analogRead(tempPin);
        tempa = tempa * 0.11;
         Serial.print("Body Temperature = ");
         Serial.print(tempa);
         Serial.print("*C");
         Serial.println();
         delay(1000);
    }
   data_effect=1;//sign bit
}
/*Function: Interrupt service routine.Get the sigal from the external interrupt*/
void interrupt()
{
    temp[counter]=millis();
    Serial.println(counter,DEC);
    switch(counter)
    {
        case 0:
            sub=temp[counter]-temp[20];

            break;
        default:
            sub=temp[counter]-temp[counter-1];

            break;
    }
    if(sub>max_heartpluse_duty)//set 2 seconds as max heart pluse duty
    {
        data_effect=0;//sign bit
        counter=0;
        Serial.println("measurement error,test will restart!" );
        arrayInit();
    }
    else if (counter==20&&data_effect)
    {
      counter=0;
      sum();
    }
    else if(counter!=20&&data_effect)
    {
    counter++;
    }
    else
    {
        counter=0;
        data_effect=1;
    }

}
/*Function: Initialization for the array(temp)*/
void arrayInit()
{
    for(unsigned char i=0;i < 20;i ++)
    {
        temp[i]=0;
    }
    temp[20]=millis();
}
```

Comment: Arduino  code  has `C` like structure while `particle photon` is in `particle JS`. The best bet is to port logic rather than code. Look at examples for each step in logic on `particle photon` and compose. Also you have tags incorrect `particle` and `photon` are not same as `particle photon`

Comment: thank you for your response @Anil_M could you please link me to relevant resources that I can use to complete this task?

Comment: https://docs.particle.io/guide/getting-started/intro/photon/